# Why can't I tile and cascade captionless windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have several child windows, all with the same parent. I want to cascade/tile these windows and was happy to find the [TileWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633554(VS.85).aspx) and [CascadeWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632674(VS.85).aspx) functions. But they don't seem to work on my windows if they don't have a caption (and they don't have one)! With caption everything is fine. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are functions that were designed to work with MDI child windows.  An MDI child window must have a caption.  If they work with non-MDI child windows too (haven't tried) then surely Windows avoids moving a window that cannot easily be moved back by the user.

Comment: You mean like Windows is afraid of accidentally moving a window out of the user's reach?

Comment: If a window doesn't have a caption then a user doesn't have an easy way to move the window.

Comment: Well I assume I have to live with this fact :-/

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows to tile / cascade windows only if the wsCaption flag of a window is set. This has to do with the original purpose, namely that these functions are mainly used in MDI applications. In addition these functions can also be used on a set of top level windows (right clicking on the task bar gives you respective menu entries) which typically have a titlebar.

Comment: But why isn't anything of this mentioned in the documentation? I find this a rather hard restriction - especially if you have to stumble over it to learn it.

Comment: Maybe because MS thaught that noone would ever want to tile/cascade captionless windows as this functionality is closely tight to MDI. Remember in MDI these functions do more than just arrange the windows - e.g. the caption of a child window becomes the caption of the main window when it is maximized. In addition it looses its own caption.